# Color coding results from COUNTIFS plus OR function

Tags: excel

I may be going about this the wrong way so if someone has an alternative method let me know.

I have two columns of values. Column A has values spanning -5 to 5 and column B has values from 1 to zero. My goal is to indicate which rows have both a Column A value of either <-1 or >1 and a Column B value <0.05. My current Excel function is:

=COUNTIFS(A1,">1",B1,"<0.05")+COUNTIFS(A1,"<-1",B1,"<0.05")

This works in that it returns a 1 if either of the criteria are met however it does not tell me which criteria was met so I was wondering if there was a way to color code the results so that if the first was met (>1 and <0.05) the cell would be green and if the second was met (<-1 and <0.05) it would be red.

Comment: Use conditional formatting?

Comment: How can I use conditional formatting for this? The result for either match is "1" so I am not sure how I can use conditional formatting to parse these out.

Comment: You're way overthinking. Look up conditional formatting. You will laugh ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formatting.

You can put several rules there. In your case they would be (assuming that values are in cells A1:B10):

```
Rule 1: =AND($A1>1;$B2<0.05)  , Color: Green , Range: =$A$1:$B$10
Rule 2: =AND($A1<-1;$B2<0.05) , Color: Red   , Range: =$A$1:$B$10
```

These rules will color whole row, i. e. cells in column A as well as in column B.

Please, note, that, in order to make formula work correctly, column address is locked with $ (if it would be absent, rule 1 formula for cell A1 would work like =AND(A1>1;B2<0.05) , and for column B1 - like =AND(B1>1;C2<0.05), which is not what we need)

P. S. In complex situations when there are overlapping rules (which is not your case), you can make set of conditional formatting rules work correctly by adjusting their order, or by setting "[ ] Stop If True" checkbox.